# All-purpose brackets for mounting small devices (tablet) on the will with an existing (small) opening

Tags: walls, mounting, lath-and-plaster

I have a small hole (~1.7"x1.7") in a lath & plaster wall where previously a home security system was mounted. I would like to place a tablet (iPad Pro Gen1) on the wall at the same place (power comes through the hole via PoE). Looks like:

[image]

Note how the previous owners completely messed up the lath & plaster wall: The lath separated from the plaster and they just jacked the security panel with drywall screws.

What is the best and no-frills way to mount a tablet on top of this?

Ideally I am looking for something similar like a low voltage bracket (like [this](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Commercial-Electric-1-Gang-Low-Voltage-Mounting-Bracket-5041/206415713)) that has metal ears that can be bent but for a much smaller hole like this. My thought is to first use a bracket to fix it flush onto the wall via the existing hole. Next screw a piece of plastic onto that bracket that locks into a piece of plastic that I glue onto the tablet (or a case).

Notes:

- I really do **not** want to increase the hole size. First, I am not sure how long term I want the tablet there and second, I created many holes in lath & plaster already and it is a time consuming PAIN. Super dirty/dusty, cutting the lath is hard and increases the chance of destroying even more (since lath separated already from the lath)
- I can't use drywall screws/hooks etc because it's lath & plaster
- I would like to avoid screws into the lath because the consistency of lath behind is unclear. I don't want to destroy more
- I am not sure how long-term I want a tablet there, hence I am looking for a "no-frills" solution that takes the least effort to get the job done

Comment: ply cap trim. You can use drywall screws. Surely the thing they touched *at least* twice a day wasn't wiggling around; not with 3 out of the 7 screws doing *anything*.

Comment: @Mazura sorry don't understand what you mean with "ply cap trim". When I google, these seem to be molding. And with "dyrwall screws" you do not mean using them in the plaster, right? That doesn't work well, tried before. Regarding last statement: I have no clue is they used it and when. The phone cables that connected to the alarm where cut in the wall cavity! No idea how this could have happened (nevertheless, the panel was sitting quite firm)

Comment: What's the brown surface?

Comment: @Huesmann the old, ugly paint

Comment: @divB depending on how secure the painted surface is, you could try a double-sided foam tape, perhaps.